# Facebook Insights for Webmasters not showing any data

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I've been following [this Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/domains) on Insights for Webmasters.

From the page, I understand that the only required step is to claim a domain. From [this third-party article](https://www.seoinc.com/seo-blog/how-to-add-facebook-insights-to-your-website/), I understand that after completing that initial step, I should have instant access to historical data.

I have added the domain using the `fb:admins` meta-tag, and it successfully shows up in my dashboard, but since I added it a few days ago, I have not seen any data at all, despite Google Analytics telling me that 75% of my website traffic is coming from Facebook.

Any suggestions as to why no data would be showing?

**Update:** My canonical url is "www" and requests without subdomain 301:s to "www", but I did not specify this when adding the domain, so it's added without a subdomain. I've suspected this as a cause, and tried to add the domain with www, but the "Get insights" dialog closes without an error (and without adding anything) so I've assumed Facebook treats www and non-www as the same domain.

I've also tried to remove the domain entirely and add it again with www, but as far as I can tell, there doesn't appear to be an option to remove it.

Comment: [Looks a lot like this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1677583369166013/), although mine is a new domain, so I can't say that it's ever worked, hence not sure.

Comment: This bug is now showing as fixed by Facebook - worth checking back to see if you've bene scraped yet!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook scrapes and updates this data weekly. It should give you a full history once the scrape is done and uploaded.

Also check to see if it's showing up on their developer site: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Any errors in your markup will cause it to fail parsing the whole thing (which is lame).

Comment: Updated this after new info added. Domain won't matter once it's verified, it's likely they just haven't gone through a scrape cycle yet.

Comment: Alright, [this is the domain](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vaccinmyter.se%2F) in the debugger. The domain was added a week ago yesterday, so I guess we'll know soon whether that was the deal. The existing scrape complains about an invalid app id. I'm guessing that because the app isn't published. However, I didn't add the site with an `app_id` initially, I just connected it through `fb:admins`, so if that's causing an issue now, that at least won't have been the issue for the entire week.

Comment: Since there's no errors, all there is to do is wait. If it doesn't show up after 7 days it's worth flagging it with Facebook!

Comment: Well no data with more than a week passed. Guessing it might be [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1677583369166013/) then.

Comment: The test I set up after this is showing the exact same issue. I'm tipping toward the bug being the issue. Facebook is notoriously bad with code fidelity due to their internal coding policies being more result driven. Don't be surprised if bugs in newer features are continuously cropping up.